# Shared models across different Cake installations on the same server

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.1

I have multiple sites on the same server, each with their own Cake install.  I want to share models across these different apps.

How do I import and use the shared model that lies outside of the app?

Comment: Maybe add some more information of the why. It seems like a non-standard solution but there is not enough info to give a more specific answer. In general this creates lots of dependencies between separate software parts which is likely not the most great solution for maintenance.

Comment: The sites share the same database.  Until now, each app has had its own model for one of the tables, but I am adding methods that need to be used on all the sites.  It is crucial that each site generates the exact same results from the methods, so I don't want to have them using their own models with copy/pasted methods.  That would leave it open to human error or forgetting to bug fix on one site's method, and not another.

Comment: Then I would suggest to build a plugin for it. That is a better solution. A plugin is re-usable and is made for this specific purpose. There are different options to share the plugin. If you use some linux server you could symlink them to the origin. Another option is to use for example a Github repository for it to store the code of the plugin. Why a plugin: It creates a clear container and can be tested. It's a clear group of code which follows MVC and the other standards applied by the framework.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [App::build](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/app.html#App%3a%3abuild) as noted in the docs

`App::build(array('Model' => array('/a/full/path/to/models/')));`